# AWS pdfminer Lambda running time exponentially increase on event trigger

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, pdfminer

I created a lambda to parse a PDF into a string using the pdfminer library. 
Whenever i trigger my lambda manually, the lambda executes in ~ 2000 millis. 
Whenever the same lambda is event triggered, the same code executes in ~ 27 700 millis.

Here is the code of my parsing function :

```
def pdfToString(path):
    try:
        output_string = StringIO()
        with open(path, 'rb') as in_file:
            parser = PDFParser(in_file)
            doc = PDFDocument(parser)
            rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
            device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, output_string, laparams=LAParams())
            interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
            for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
                interpreter.process_page(page)
        fileContent = output_string.getvalue()
        return deletePDFHeader(fileContent)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return 'NONE'
```

This method is called from the lambda_handler main function, and the running is logged using the date.time function. 
Could anyone help me understand why there is such a time gap betweem the two cases?

Thank you, 
Regards

Comment: Which event triggers the lambda function ? SNS and S3?

Comment: can you include the code for the lambda handler which is invoked by the event and passes data to this function?